# How to join two tables with one-to-many relationship in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have these two simple tables in MS access or MySQL.

[image]

I want to find what are the products ordered by customer B ?
what SQL query should i write?

I tried this.. why its wrong!!

```
SELECT PRODUCT FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.CUST_ID=table2.CUST_ID
WHERE table1.NAME='B' ;
```

This may be a very easy question, but please answer...i want to learn, Thank you very much..

Comment: If you wish to learn then please show us the code you have tried already and we'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Ok so what happens when you run that code? An error? Or an unexpected result? It looks like it would work ok

Comment: P.s. why are you asking about Access and MySQL? Which one are you actually using? There may occasionally be differences in syntax which would result in a different answer in each case

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`

```
select
    product
from product p
where exists (
    select
        cust_id
    from customer c
    where p.cust_id = c.cust_id
    and name = 'B'
 )
```

output:

```
| product |
| ------- |
| K       |
| M       |
```

Comment: It would undoubtedly help the OP and others who are just learning SQL to explain why you think this is the solution. What have you changed from the original code, and more importantly, for what purpose? That would make a much more useful answer :-)

Comment: However I don't think exists should be necessary in this simple case. Why do you think that a join can't work?

Comment: @ADyson . . . (1) Exists is probably more efficient.  (2) Exists doesn't produce duplicates.  (3) Exists is a basic part of the language, so it hardly seems necessary to explain it, any more than I would suggest explaining what `where` does`.  It should be sufficient to point out that it is  an appropriate solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok points 1 and 2 I accept, but since it's fairly clear from the question that the OP (and anyone else searching for this kind of thing) is likely to be a beginner, I still think it merits at least a basic explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on (t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id)
where
t1.name = 'B'
```

Comment: It would undoubtedly help the OP and others who are just learning SQL to explain _why_ you think this is the solution. What have you changed from the original code, and more importantly, for what purpose? That would make a much more useful answer :-)